# File Edit Archive In Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

a few days ago, I wrote a code and then saved this file. Day by day, I edited this file. And now, I need the first variant of my code, which I made a few days ago. But I can't remember the first variant of my code. My question: Is there any chance to get the first variant of code in Sublime Text or another program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you kept your editor open this whole time?

- Yes → Hold down Ctrl+Z.
- No ↓

  - Are you using Dropbox (or any similar service) or Windows with file history turned on, or have regular automatic backups that happened to take place between then and now?

    - Yes → Try that
    - No → Learn from your mistake and use [version control](http://git-scm.com/) next time, all the time.

Comment: I am using Dropbox, but my file isn't in Dropbox folder. And how can I know is my Windows file history turned on?

Comment: @ZiyaddinSadigov: If you didn’t turn it on, it’s not on.